# Echo a json with Php adding characters

Tags: php, json, encode

I'm trying to generate a jqplot Graph. I've got a simple problem, but i can't manage to find any solution, i would greatly appreciate if you could help me, i would in return too if i'm able too, hi hi.

Jqplot Graph needs this kind of JSON data (3 "[" characters both at the beggining and at the end):

```
[[["Sciences",5],["Lettres",2],["Informatique",1],["Commerce",1],["Technologie 1",1]]]
```

This is the working PHP code I use to generate it (except the json_encode() part explained below):

```
$lectureSql5="SELECT distinct count(professeur.idcategcours) as decompte,categcours.nom as nom FROM professeur INNER JOIN categcours ON professeur.idcategcours=categcours.idcategcours group by professeur.idcategcours";
$lecture5 = mysql_query($lectureSql5) or die(mysql_error());

while ($col=mysql_fetch_array($lecture5)){ 
    $col[0]=intval($col[0]); 
    $tabGen[]=array($col[1],$col[0]);
};  



echo json_encode($tabGen);


file_put_contents('g1.json', '['.json_encode($tabGen).']');
```

As you can see, after the array creation, I try to json_encode and i get this on my html page :

```
[["Sciences",5],["Lettres",2],["Informatique",1],["Commerce",1],["Technologie 1",1]]
```

This is a big problem, because i miss the three "[" characters both at the beggining and at the end of the line !

So i've managed to do it with  file_put_contents('g1.json', '['.json_encode($tabGen).']'); and it works, but it is not what i need, it's creating a file !

I need the line to appear directly with json_encode into the web navigator!

I thought about creating a main php array, for having the three "[" and "]" but i dont know how to do ?

I've tried :

```
echo('['.json_encode($tabGen).']');
```

but that doesn't work too , snif!

So what i need is this line directly into my navigator :

```
 [[["Sciences",5],["Lettres",2],["Informatique",1],["Commerce",1],["Technologie 1",1]]]
```

I would grealty appreciate it if you could help me, i will if i can in return with javascript jquery problems or jqplot tips. 
thank you have a niiiiiice day "hi hi" ! ah ah

EDIT : ITS OK I JUST HAVE FOUND THE SOLUTION

```
$tabAdded=json_encode($tabGen);

echo('['.$tabAdded.']');
```

Then, the line print correctly with 3 "[[[" and 3 "]]]" thank you

Comment: Don't try to construct JSON by hand. Create an array with the whole structure that you want, and then use `json_encode()` on that.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Yes i think about creating a main array(for example called $main), and, after, to push $tabGen into it, and finally, json_encode($main), but it's not so easy to do, i've tried push(), but it's not really what i need, and it's difficult to me to do it.

Comment: It's ok ! Just found the solution ! Probably it was because i've descriped the problem . Just add     
$tabAdded=json_encode($tabGen);

echo('['.$tabAdded.']');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got it right, you want to output array inside array which contains arrays.

There is no magic, just wrap your array with another array to get the required result.

```
header('content-type', 'application/json');
echo json_encode([$a]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another array-level before json_encode

```
file_put_contents('g1.json', json_encode([$tabGen]));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do i flag my stuff as RESOLVED ? I can't find the button.